# How to make scroll keep down, but don't want to lock

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I am making Shoutbox. So I want that when it retrieves data it keep scroll down. Just like in facebook the scroll keep remains down. I am using javascript for it but goes lock, so it prevent from scroll top.
I am using this code  :

```
document.getElementById('txtHint').scrollTop = 10000;  

<div id="txtHint" style="width:700px;height:500px;overflow:auto;" >
<!-- Here data will be displayed -->
</div>
```

The only problem is that, it prevents me from scrolling up.

Comment: Are you setting `scrollTop` just once or continuously using `setInterval()` ?

Comment: Yeah ! I am continuously using setInterval()

Comment: Thats the problem. Set `scrollTop` only after retrieving and setting fresh data each time. Remove the `setInterval()` call.

Comment: Actually I am calling setInterval() for retrivng data continuously.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the offsetTop property. I suggest putting a hidden div at the end of the div in which the text will scroll down(hidden div should alwasy be at the bottom), and then you should apply the scrollTop

```
document.getElementById('txtHint').scrollTop = document.getElementById('s_hidden').OffsetTop;  

<div id="txtHint" style="width:700px;height:500px;overflow:auto;" >
<!-- Here data will be displayed -->
<div id="s_hidden"></div>
</div>
```